# Find the sum of the values of $x$ such that $\cos^3 3x+ \cos^3 5x = 8 \cos^3 4x \cos^3 x$, where $x$ is measured in degrees and $100< x< 200$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here's the problem statement(same as the title):

> Find the sum of the values of $x$ such that $\cos^3 3x+ \cos^3 5x = 8 \cos^3 4x \cos^3 x$, where $x$ is measured in degrees and $100< x< 200.$ -- AIME 2006 I #12

Here's the solution:

> Observe that $2\cos 4x\cos x = \cos 5x + \cos 3x$ by the sum-to-> product formulas. Defining $a = \cos 3x$ and $b = \cos 5x$, we have $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 \rightarrow ab(a+b) = 0$. But $a+b = 2\cos 4x\cos x$, so we require $\cos x = 0$, $\cos 3x = 0$, $\cos 4x = 0$, or $\cos 5x = 0$.
> Hence we see by careful analysis of the cases that the solution set is $A = \{150, 126, 162, 198, 112.5, 157.5\}$ and thus $\sum_{x \in A} x = \boxed{906}$.

Specifically, I know the sum-to-product formulas, but I'm not quite getting how they jumped from the original equation to $2\cos 4x\cos x = \cos 5x + \cos 3x$. I tried asking ChatGPT, but it gave long, inaccurate responses. Could someone expand on it, or offer an alternative solution?

Comment: It looks like you cut of part of the solution, after "and...". Please include that, it may contain more needed details.

Comment: @coffeemath see my edits

Comment: @codexistent, read my answer and tell me if you like it.

Comment: forget chatgpt !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos^33x+\cos^35x=8\cos^34x\cos^3x$

is equivalent to

$\cos^33x+\cos^35x=\left(2\cos4x\cos x\right)^3$

Then you can use the [cosine addition and subtraction formulas](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Book%3A_Precalculus__An_Investigation_of_Functions_(Lippman_and_Rasmussen)/07%3A_Trigonometric_Equations_and_Identities/7.02%3A_Addition_and_Subtraction_Identities) :

$\cos 5x+\cos3x=\color{blue}{\cos(4x+x)}+\color{red}{\cos(4x-x)}=$

$=\color{blue}{\cos4x\cos x-\sin4x\sin x}+\color{red}{\cos4x\cos x+\sin4x\sin x}=$

$=2\cos4x\cos x$

Consequently the original equation is equivalent to

$\cos^33x+\cos^35x=\left(\cos5x+\cos3x\right)^3\;\;,$

$\cos5x\cos3x\,(\cos5x+\cos3x)=0\;\;,$

$2\cos5x\cos3x\cos4x\cos x=0\,.$